# How do I recover lost achievements?

Tags: achievements, xbox-network, xbox-360

A few weeks ago my cousin recovered his Gamertag on my Xbox 360 because we were playing Xplosion Man at my place and he wanted to get the achievements. Some time after, he started playing Red Dead Redemption at his place (and in his Xbox), getting almost all the achievements. Because his Gold membership had expired, he didn't bother to recover his Gamertag on his console, but when he finally did, all the achievements he had gotten on Red Dead Redemption were lost.

Is there any way to get them back? His game files are OK, so now it looks like he has 100% of some stuff but no achievements to go with them.

Comment: I think you mean "Recover gamertag"?

Comment: Its happend to me, i lost my oblivion exit the sewers achievement, gutted as it shows and recognises i have them all, but i lost 50g and i now have 59 of 60 achievements shown on x-box live... so to get that back i need to apparently sign on to my origional x-box... but if i do do i need the same hard drive or seperate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, if you are not connected to xbox live when you earn an achievement that achievement is stored on your local box.

If you then go and recover your gamer tag to a new box, the new box (and live.xbox.com) won't show those achievements.  To have your achievements unified across all media you need to sign the box that earned them back into xbox live on that account.

Recovering your gamertag is a special processes where your gamertag is transfered to a new box and retroactively removed from all other boxes.  Because you removed it from his old xbox before updating that achievements, you necessarily lost your ability to update those achievement.

I'm sorry, but you should always connect to xbox live whenever possible if you want to maintain your achievements.  God forbid your box red rings and you lose all your work.

Comment: He wasnt connected and was playing in his own box, but his gamertag was last recover in my box. After he recovered his gamertag in his box the achievments were lost... I've re-written the question, I think its clearer now

Comment: Like I said when he recovered his gamer tag it was removed from his old box and he lost those achievements.

Answer (score 1):

From [this support page](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/settings-and-initial-setup/profile-move-delete):

"Any achievements or changes that you have made since the account last connected to Xbox LIVE will be lost during the recovery process."

It's sad, but no luck, it's gone for good.

Comment: Are you quoting a source here?  Can you link us to where you read it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're talking about, but if achievements are earned on a separate console, the achievements should still be earned for that gamertag, but you might have to recover the gamertag on the original console to get those achievements visible.

If the achievements were earned on a different gamertag, then they were effectively earned by someone else. You might be able to merge gamertags, but that would require assistance from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

He may get his achievements back when he gets next achievement in RDR.

It happened to me that my last achievement in Halo Wars did not register on server for some reason. (I guess they had a bug, it happened to many others as well.) I got that achievement together with the first achievement of DLC when DLC arrived.

So, my theory is that when Xbox submits achievement data to server, it always reports all achievements together. (Makes sense when submitting bunch of achievements one got offline.) Or maybe, only some games (Halo Wars) do that. Anyway, there is still a hope.

Comment: Those are actually two (or possibly three) different situations. Glitched achievements can be retroactively awarded when a patch is issued. If you play offline, get achievements, and then recover your gamertag on the console where you earned those achievements without first connecting to Xbox Live, they will be overwritten - your game files will remain, but those offline achievements are lost. However, achievements that stack will be rewarded when you earn an appropriate achievement, and counting achievements may also be rewarded during your next session.